Why does unregistering an existing but useless service worker cause an external script to finally load?
I have come across a very strange occurrence happening on a webpage I am working on. This has only become a recent issue as we have implemented an external cookie management system, this is loaded through a script tag which is attached to the page via an angular service.
The strange behaviour however is that for some users the script does not load, these users are ones that have seen this website before on their browser (thus have done some caching) in the past. New browsers or incognito mode have no issues and the script loads fine everytime. The error appears to originate from the very simple service worker present that looks like this:
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});

This SW above doesn't appear to do anything and it is probably present there just to trigger the browser to show the "add to home screen" (a2hs) banner on mobile devices.
The error given, highlighted under the fetch(event.request) part, is as follows:
X Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
X Refused to connect to `https://example.com/etc' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob blob: data:
[Various domains not including the one above]
X Refused to connect to 'https://example.com/etc' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

(example.com in this case is the external script)
For testing we had disabled the CSPs and the error persists. It also persists with new updated CSPs that account for the new domains including the cookie management domain. With the error itself mentioned above, altogether indicate to me that perhaps it's an old cached CSP on some user's browsers.
Opening the devtools and unregistering the Service worker via the applications tab fixes this issue forever on the browser. The service worker would be re-registered anyway by the page but the error never occurs again and the script will load.
My questions are as follows, what would be causing this, especially considering how rudimentary the service worker is and it doesn't appear to be doing any caching in code?
More importantly, what would be the best approach to fix this issue, perhaps to unregister the service worker programmatically or maybe to 'cache-bust' the service worker if possible? But would this remove what looks like a cached CSP?
